# What is the difference in the use of construction member and local assignment?

Tags: c#

Hello guy am learning the use for constructor and i will like to ask what is the key deference between the two code snipets i have below.

I am assigning _fristname instance vairable to a local varibale i created in Human construction.

```
public string _firstName;

public Humans()
        {
            string name = "";
            _firstName = name;
        }
```

I am assigning local variable name to instance _fristname.

```
public string _firstName;

public Humans()
        {
            string name;
            name = _firstName;
        }
```

also why is it when i use public access modifier to string name to  public

```
Humans()
        {
            public string name;
            name = _firstName;
        }
```

THe whole code in that class gets red error lines? why cant local var get a public access modifier within a constructor, also point out from the three code snipets which ones is a no no.

I will like to know what is the main use for a constructor apart from a template for the creation of instance into object of a class types.

Comment: You assign what's on the right side to what's on the left side: `_firstName = name`. You assing `name` to `_firstName`, not the other way around. See to what members the [public](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/public) access modifier applies to.

Comment: public/private/internal modifiers are for types and type members, not local variables.

Comment: Hello why is assigning what on the right side to what on the left side the case and also, why do i need to presume the instance member var belong on the right side or what make it goes to the right side. is it like saying                                    int number1; then number = 4; in this case 4 represent the user define value in a constructor? I think i understand what you mean thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the formatting of the question is difficult to read. It would help if you formatted it properly so the indentation is correct, and the code isn't mixed with text. But I think I see what your getting at.

```
// I'm not sure if you just left this out, or if you're missing it in your 
// actual class, but need to declare the class.
public class Humans {
    Humans() {
        // The reason this doesn't work is because it's not a member of the class.
        // you can only use access modifiers on a class member
        public string name;
    }
}
```

In the above, the variable is declared inside the constructor. If it's declared in the constructor, then it only exists in the constructor. Once you leave the constructor, it goes away.

If you wanted to have a public member name that is part of the class, you declare it in the class.

```
public class Humans {
    public string name;

    public Humans() {
        name = "Some value here...";
    }
}
```

In this example, the Humans object has a property name that will be accessible as long as your human instance exists.

```
Humans human = new Humans();
string humanName = human.name;
```

So if we create a new instance of the Humans object, we can access the name property. Access modifiers like public, private, etc allow you to control the access of these properties once the object is constructed. So they only apply to values that belong to the class. When you declare a variable within the constructor, that variable belongs to the constructor, not the class. So when the constructor is done executing, the variables declared within the constructor are done too. But if you declare the variable within the scope of the class itself, then the variable will stick around as long as the class does. And because accessing that variable requires you to go through an instance of the class, you can control the access of that variable with an access modifier. private means only code that is written within the class can access it, and public means anything that has access to an instance of the class can access it.

So just as a simple example of how access modifiers work, here's an example Humans class.

```
public class Humans {
    // These variables are accessible only by code within this class block.
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;

    // This constructor is public, so it could be accessed anywhere.
    public Humans(string firstName, string lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // This function is public, so can be called to get the full name.
    public string getFullName() {
        // the variable fullName only exists in the scope of this function.
        // so there is no point in applying an access modifier.
        string fullName = String.format("{} {}", this.firstName, this.lastName);
        // When we return fullName, we return a copy of the value, and the 
        // original variable gets cleaned up.
        return fullName;
    }

    // Lets say we want to allow updating the name, but we want to verify
    // that the name is valid first. We can make public setters.
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        if (!String.isNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName)) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("First name cannot be null or empty.")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your explanation really helps me and it clarified what i wanst sure of.